# Should I hard code references to my node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm creating an npm package called `ctgen` and I need to reference a folder within that package. Should I hard code the reference to that folder?

e.g. `src = './node_modules/ctgen/scaffold'`

or is there a pre-made function that will do this for me?

For a bit more clarity on my issue. I have the following function in my package:

```
var createFile = function (fileName, componentName, doc) {
  // Tell the user what is happening
  console.log(chalk.blue('\nCreating', fileName, '...'))
  // Bring in the scaffold files (note this should point to the scaffold folder in node modules/ctgen)
  var scaffold = './scaffold/' + fileName
  fs.readFile(scaffold, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(chalk.red(err))
    var result = data.replace(/%cname%/g, componentName)
    if (doc) {
      var d = new Date()
      result = result.replace(/%cfname%/g, doc.componentName)
      result = result.replace(/%cdesc%/g, doc.componentDesc)
      result = result.replace(/%cauthor%/g, doc.userName)
      result = result.replace(/%cagithub%/g, doc.userGithub)
      result = result.replace(/%creationdate%/g, d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getFullYear())
    }

    fs.writeFile('./src/components/' + componentName + '/' + fileName, result, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(chalk.red(err))
      console.log(chalk.green(fileName, 'created!'))
    })
  })
}
```

It looks in a folder called scaffold for the following files:

- view.php
- style.styl
- component.json

It then pulls the file into a cache, performs a find and replace on some strings and then writes the output to a file in the users project.

It seems though that whenever I try to reference the `'scaffold'` folder, it's trying to find it in the users project folder and not in my package folder.

I'm very hesitant to reference the scaffold folder by writing `'/node_modules/ctgen/scaffold'` as that seems like the wrong thing to do to me.

Comment: Could you clarify what you need and why? Is there a reason why the ctgen module can't export what you need? How do you ensure the file will be there?

Comment: I've added some more info. Sorry it seems I made it sound like it had an external dependency when that is not the case. I want to know how to make sure my package can see it's own folder structure when installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `__dirname`.

If I understand your question, you have a ressource folder contained in your module, and have trouble accessing it since the current path is the path of the app, not your module.

`__dirname` will contain the path of your script file, and so will point to your module file.

I presume your module is named ctgen, and the files you want to access are in ctgen/scaffold. So in your code, try to access `__dirname/scaffold`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In short **NO**. If you want to read more about how node looks for required files pleas  read this: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_addenda_package_manager_tips

Comment: Thanks. This isn't about loading modules though, merely accessing a folder in my packages own internal file structure when installed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating an npm package, specify your dependent npm modules within your `package.json` and use them as intended in node (with `require('your-dependent-module-name')`). After you published your module and someone `npm install --save your-module`, it will also install your dependencies into `[usrDir]/node_modules/[your-module]/node_modules`, where your module will find what it needs.

That beeing said; yes, you *could* reference `__dirname + 'node_modules/[something]` but that wouldn't be smart as it makes assumptions how the user is using your module. At the same time, node+npm solves this problem for you, so there is no reason for you to want to do this)

Comment: Thanks. I think my question wasn't clear. This has nothing to do with external dependencies, I just want to be able to access my packages own internal folder structure when someone installs it. I've added some more info to my question. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now.